# How can I type URLs using shape writing?

Tags: 8.1, wordflow

One of the new features of WP 8.1 is shape writing, where I swipe over the keyboard instead of tapping every key individually.

When I try to input a URL using shape writing, let's say:

```
windowsphone.com
```

I try to input `windows`, then `phone`, then I press the <kbd>.com</kbd> key. What I get is:

```
windows phone.com
```

which leads me to a Bing search instead of the site.

This forces me to select and delete the whitespace in between words as they are added automatically.

---

Is there any faster and more comfortable way to use shape writing for URLs?

Comment: I swiped over `windowsphone` and then tapped `.com`, shows `windowsphone.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type more than one word and tapping .com, the .com will appended after a space. While typing urls try type/swipe over a single word and then .com/.us

I swiped over windowsphone and then tapped .com, shows windowsphone.com

Comment: I just tested it, and swiping `windowsphone` as a single word does indeed work. However, that's just one working example out of billions. I can't swipe `stackoverflow` without swiping `stack` then `overflow`. The problem is every time I swipe, a whitespace is added in front of the new word. Do you maybe know how to change that behavior so WP adds whitespaces after the swiped word instead?

Comment: That's is the default behaviour as the intention is that the user is trying to put search queries (unless single word ends with domain). For the use cases above, try bookmark the url or wait for bing suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly how the Wordflow interface works, but from experience of using other similar systems (Swype, et al), here is what I do:

1. Swipe `windows` or `stack`
2. Now, swiping another word adds a space before the next word. To counter this, press `space` then `backspace` (the software's automatic spacing breaks for this)
3. Type your second word `phone` or `overflow`

Win Win Win.

Also, it'd be better if you add it to the dictionary for quicker access in the future.

Comment: Didn't work. Swiping a word automatically adds a whitespace in front of it except for the first word. What it *does* break, is word deletion; when you press the backspace it deletes characters individually instead of the whole word.

Comment: Then the best way would be adding it to your dictionary.

Comment: I agree, though that's what IE's auto-complete feature is for. Neither help when I'm trying to enter a URL for the first time. Thanks for taking your time to answer my question, though. Much appreciated ;)